# Imported script does not compile with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm struggling to integrate an external script in my ReactJS application.

Let's assume this external script is called `myScript.js`. I am pretty sure this detail is irrelevant, but this script is generated from OCaml bytecode using [Js_of_ocaml](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/).

`myScript.js` works as expected when executed with node, i.e.,

```
$ node myScript.js
```

However, when I import this file to my ReactJS application, using either `require` or `import`, and execute my application with

```
$ npm start
```

It does not succeed.

```
ERROR in ./src/myScript.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: /Projects/myProject/src/myScript.js: Line must be greater than or equal to 1, got 0
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_findMapping [as _findMapping] (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:539:13)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_allGeneratedPositionsFor [as allGeneratedPositionsFor] (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:201:22)
    at /Projects/myProject/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:184:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
    at buildMappingData (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:145:12)
    at mergeSourceMap (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:19:17)
    at generateCode (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/generate.js:72:39)
    at run (/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:53:33)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
 @ ./src/TimeGrid.js 15:18-60
 @ ./src/App.js 16:0-34 188:45-53
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

ERROR in src/myScript.js
  Line 1026:29:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
no-unused-expressions
  Line 2033:15:   React Hook "useKaratsuba" is called in function "BigInteger.prototype.multiply" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 2558:29:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression                                                                                                                                                                                                    
no-unused-expressions
  Line 4269:7:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression                                                                                                                                                                                                    
no-unused-expressions
  Line 30953:17:  Unexpected use of 'event'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
no-restricted-globals
  Line 30963:26:  Unexpected use of 'event'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack 5.66.0 compiled with 2 errors and 2 warnings in 118769 ms
```

I'm no expert, but considering that I set up this application with `create-react-app`, and that the script works just fine with `node`, I assume that either `webpack` or `babel` are transpiling the script, and this is probably why the errors arise.
Hence, I try to avoid the transpilation of `myScript.js` by excluding it from `babel` and `webpack` using the config files, as described in [Babel exclude](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#exclude) and [Module Rule.exclude](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleexclude).

I know that since I set up the application with `create-react-app`, I need to either run `npm eject` or to override the default config somehow. To achieve this without ejecting the application, I use [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra). First, I try to exclude it from `babel`:

```
const { override, babelExclude, addBabelPresets } = require('customize-cra')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  babelExclude([path.resolve("./src/myScript.js")]),
  addBabelPresets(["@babel/env", { modules: false }])
);
```

Unfortunately, the error persists. Subsequently, I try to add an exclude rule to `webpack`:

```
const { override, babelExclude, addBabelPresets, addWebpackModuleRule } = require('customize-cra')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  babelExclude([path.resolve("./src/myScript.js")]),
  addBabelPresets(["@babel/env", { modules: false }]),
  addWebpackModuleRule({ exclude: path.resolve("./src/myScript.js") })
);
```

but this apparently disables the transpilation step for all files altogether:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 10:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
|     <App />
|   </React.StrictMode>,

webpack 5.66.0 compiled with 1 error in 2317 ms
```

What can I do next to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up realizing that adding `myScript.js` as an [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) in my `webpack` config would do the trick. However, I was unable to change my config file and make it work.

Instead, I simply added a script tag to the head of `public/index.html`, *i.e.*,

```
<script
    src="myScript.js"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
```